# Ubuntu 16.04 startup script not working

Tags: 16.04, scripts, startup

I have a simple script(upload postgresql db dump to google drive) and if I run this script in terminal, everything works fine. 
Now i want to run this script at system start up

I add my script to folder `/etc/init.d`, name of the script is `gdrive-upload`:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          gdrive-upload
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
sleep 60
while true; do 
    name=$(date -d "today" +"dev_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M").dump
    PGPASSWORD='passToDB' pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U lm -F c -b -v -f /postgresql/dump/${name} DBname
    gdrive upload /postgresql/dump/${name}
    sudo rm  /postgresql/dump/${name}
    sleep 3600
done
```

file prmission of this file is : `755`

To do this script executable I run `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/gdrive-upload` After this no output

Then `sudo update-rc.d gdrive-upload defaults` After this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (1 6) of script `gdrive-upload' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

But script is not running after `sudo reboot`

But if I run `/etc/init.d/gdrive-upload` in terminal, everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Ubuntu 16.04 which uses `systemd` you might want to use the `systemd` native service and timer combination.

Put the actual work into a script. E.g. `/usr/local/sbin/gdrive-upload.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 

name=$(date -d "today" +"dev_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M").dump
PGPASSWORD='passToDB' pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U lm -F c -b -v -f /postgresql/dump/${name} DBname
gdrive upload /postgresql/dump/${name}
sudo rm  /postgresql/dump/${name}
```

A corresponding service `/etc/systemd/system/gdrive-upload.service` file would look like as follows, but might need some tweaks.

```
[Unit]
Description=Upload stuff to gdrive
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/gdrive-upload.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you need a `systemd` timer `/etc/systemd/system/gdrive-upload.timer` to run the service file on a regular basis.

```
[Unit]
Description=Regularly upload stuff to gdrive

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

After you have created the files you have to tell `systemd` that there are new services available to pickup and enable the timer.

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable gdrive-upload.timer
$ systemctl start gdrive-upload.timer
```

Do not enable the `gdrive-upload.service` as this will be triggered by the timer.

Now you can watch your timer when it was triggered last and when it will be triggered next time with `systemclt list-timers`.
As already mentioned, you may need to tweak the timer and the service a bit, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm getting this error:
`Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument`, when run `systemctl enable gdrive-upload.timer`.

Comment: I assume, i badly create `gdrive-upload.timer` file, because I just run `cp -rp /etc/systemd/system/sshd.service /etc/systemd/system/gdrive-upload.timer` and paste your code for timer

Comment: Hm...might be. Just tested again and did not have an error. If you still experience problems, could you post the output of `journalctl -u gdrive-upload.timer`.

Comment: output: -- No entries --

Comment: Hm...any luck with `systemctl status gdrive-upload.timer`?

Comment: `● gdrive-upload.timer
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: Ok, it was problem with gdrive-*.service file, because content of this file was from timer file, so I fix this, and after `$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable gdrive-upload.timer`, nothing changed but error was new :), and i decided to reboot server, and now, server can't start up, I guess because of my "manipulations", is that any chance I can up server without reinstall? my server on ms azure

Comment: btw line `$cat /etc/systemd/system/gdrive-upload.timer` should be in the file or not? I don't know what this line means, so I keep it in the file, but now I think it was a mistake

Comment: No, `cat` is a command to show the entry of a file followed by the filenames itself and `$` is a generic placeholder indicating a shell prompt.

Comment: Do you have a console on ms azure letting you access the terminal directly without ssh? Might be due to copied the service file from ssh service file without deleting the ssh relevant part?

Comment: Yes, I can connect via console, also before all this problem with server I accidentally deleted `apt-daily.timer` file from `/etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/`. So I remove files(which I created before) *.sh, *.service, *.timer, reboot the server, but it didn't work

Comment: when I'm trying to connect to server via `ssh`, I'm getting  `Connection refused` instantly, what could went wrong ?:) And maybe there is some way to fix this? In AZURE console I can connect to the server

Comment: Ok, i found the problem. For some reason my sshd.service file is containing info from timer file, so i somehow replace sshd content, mb there is some way to return it back ? :)

Comment: `sudo service ssh status` returns: `ssh.service - Upload stuff to gdrive
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-03-15 16:49:01 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 1852 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/gdrive-upload.sh (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 1852 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74575/discussion-between-thomas-and-user2870934).